# PHP Notice: Undefined offset

Tags: php, mysql, excel

I want to upload the csv data to mysql excluding the header. My script works, but is showing the error

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 32 in C:\wamp\www\mvc\excel\upload.php on line 38
```

messages after executing the query. What is wrong and how do I fix it.

Here is my code

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {


    //Import uploaded file to Database

    $file = $_FILES['filename']['tmp_name']; 

    $handle = fopen($file,"r"); 

    //loop through the csv file and insert into database 
    for ($lines = 0; $data = fgetcsv($handle,1000,",",'"'); $lines++) {
        if ($lines == 0) continue;
        if ($data[0]) {

            $import="INSERT into contacts 
                  (name, contacttype, nationality, mobile1, country1,
                  email1, phone, fax, twon, area, restatus, retype, 
                  reproject1, contactgroup, freezone1, gender, 
                  dateofbirth, married, children, educationlevel, 
                  jobsector, driverslicense, media, media2, age, 
                  salary, created, upload, image, companyname, 
                  businesscategory, subcategory, jobrole, upload_id)
                  values('$data[0]', '$data[1]','$data[2]','$data[3]',
                         '$data[4]', $data[5]','$data[6]','$data[7]',
                         '$data[8]','$data[9]','$data[10]','$data[11]',
                         '$data[12]','$data[13]','$data[14]','$data[15]',
                         '$data[16]','$data[17]','$data[18]','$data[19]',
                         '$data[20]','$data[21]','$data[22]','$data[23]',
                         '$data[24]','$data[25]','$data[26]','$data[27]',
                         '$data[28]','$data[29]','$data[30]','$data[31]',
                         '$data[32]','$uploadid') ";
            print $import;
            mysql_query($import) or die(mysql_error());
        }

        fclose($handle);

        print "Import done";

        //view upload form
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: jobrole column value may not present in your csv file

Comment: where is line 38 in your code?

Comment: line 38 is $import="INSERT into contacts(name.......)

Comment: @AyyanarG i check jobrole is presnt in my csv file

Comment: check the value of data['32'] its return value or null

Comment: @satishrajak yes it retrun null because i csv it doesn't have data

Comment: check if(isset($data['32']))
    {$data['32'];}
    else{$data['32']="";}

Comment: I think you also need to move your `fclose($handle)` outside the for loop as well.

Comment: @satishrajak it's doesn't show the error but i't shows new error Warning: fgetcsv(): 5 is not a valid stream resource in C:\wamp\www\mvc\excel\upload.php on line 33

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Undefined offset" means that the code is referred to missing array index.
To prevent this you should use like this:

```
for ($lines = 0; $data = fgetcsv($handle,1000,",",'"'); $lines++) {
        if ($lines == 0) continue;
        for ($i = 0; $i <= 32; $i ++)
        {
            if (!isset($data[$i]))
                $data[$i] = ''; 
        }

                $import="INSERT into contacts 
                  (name, contacttype, nationality, mobile1, country1,
                  email1, phone, fax, twon, area, restatus, retype, 
                  reproject1, contactgroup, freezone1, gender, 
                  dateofbirth, married, children, educationlevel, 
                  jobsector, driverslicense, media, media2, age, 
                  salary, created, upload, image, companyname, 
                  businesscategory, subcategory, jobrole, upload_id)
                  values('$data[0]', '$data[1]','$data[2]','$data[3]',
                         '$data[4]', $data[5]','$data[6]','$data[7]',
                         '$data[8]','$data[9]','$data[10]','$data[11]',
                         '$data[12]','$data[13]','$data[14]','$data[15]',
                         '$data[16]','$data[17]','$data[18]','$data[19]',
                         '$data[20]','$data[21]','$data[22]','$data[23]',
                         '$data[24]','$data[25]','$data[26]','$data[27]',
                         '$data[28]','$data[29]','$data[30]','$data[31]',
                         '$data[32]','$uploadid') ";
                print $import;
                mysql_query($import) or die(mysql_error());
}
fclose($handle);
print "Import done";
```

Comment: Do him a favour, move the `fclose` and the `print` outside the for loop. Or his next error will be reading from an unopened file